# Possible way to get rid of abominable function types in C++?

Tags: c++, function, templates, metaprogramming, function-qualifier

So I was recently exposed to the grotesqueness that is the so-called "abominable function type" in C++ (originates from this paper as far as I know: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html). I thought about it for a while and it does seem to make some amount of sense, but everything would be much cleaner and more satisfying if one were to somehow remove them from the language completely.

Maybe there are other points of origin, but (for me at least) most issues with abominable function types come from handling member functions. If I want to get the type of a member function, I do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_ptr_to_member { using type = T; };

template <typename T, typename class_t>
struct remove_ptr_to_member<T class_t::*> { using type = T; };

struct container {
   void func() const;
};

using member_function_type = typename remove_ptr_to_member<decltype(container::func)>::type;
```

Since there exists a `const` in the declaration of `func()`, removing the pointer-to-member part leaves us with an abominable function.

This could be avoided if one were to put the invisible `this` argument into the type of member functions. Then, the things that would normally cause an abominable function would all be applied to the `this` argument (`const` would mean a `const this` pointer, `&&` would mean an rvalue reference to an instance of `this`, etc...).

Now, even if you remove the pointer-to-member part of the type, all that you're left with is a totally normal function type. The great thing about this would be that it would cut down on the amount of boiler-plate you have to write when implementing things like `is_function`.

Classic method:

```
// primary template
template<class>
struct is_function : std::false_type { };
 
// specialization for regular functions
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)> : std::true_type {};
 
// specialization for variadic functions such as std::printf
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args......)> : std::true_type {};
 
// specialization for function types that have cv-qualifiers
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) const> : std::true_type {};
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) volatile> : std::true_type {};
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) const volatile> : std::true_type {};
// etc... (goes on for a while)
```

New method:

```
// primary template
template <typename>
struct is_function : std::false_type { };

// specialization for regular functions
template<typename Ret, typname... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...)> : std::true_type { };

// specialization for variadic functions such as std::printf
template<typename Ret, typname... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args......)> : std::true_type { };

// same thing but with noexcept
template<typename Ret, typname... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args...) noexcept> : std::true_type { };
template<typename Ret, typname... Args>
struct is_function<Ret(Args......) noexcept> : std::true_type { };
```

And that would be it. No long boiler-plate required, since all the intricasies (`const`, `volatile`, etc...) are hidden within the first argument.

I'm sorry for waiting so long before asking the actual question, but the time has come:
Does anyone have a counter-argument to this fix? Is it even a fix, maybe it doesn't deal with everything there is to deal with? I guess what I'm wondering is, why this isn't in the standard? If it's such a great idea, someone must have thought of it right? There has got to be some extra information that I haven't considered, because this seems too simple.

Comment: I'm voting to close this  as opinion-based. Also, I wonder if C++23's ["Deducing this"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp23-deducing-this/) feature will play into this issue at all, since it makes the `this` argument more explicit.

Comment: Not really answering the question, but technically `is_function` isn't that hard to implement. It can be implemented much easier by testing for whether `T&` is a reference (functions can't be references), and whether `const T` is `const` (same thing). If `T&` isn't a reference _and_ `const T` isn't `const`, then it's a function.

Comment: @Human-Compiler I think you meant to test whether `T` is a reference. Reference-to-function do exist. See also the suggested implementation at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function. But I don't think there is any simple solution to implement e.g. a trait removing `const` qualifiers from these function types.

Comment: @user17732522 My mistake; but yes that was the pattern I was referring to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much exactly what you are suggesting has already been accepted for C++23 as member functions with *explicit object parameters* like this:

```
struct container {
    void func(this container const&);
};
```

The type of this function is then `void(container const&)` instead of `void() const` or equivalently the type of `&container::func` will be `void(*)(container const&)` instead of `void (container::*)() const`.

See [P0847](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p0847r7.html#writing-function-pointer-types) which introduced this new feature.

But that is not going to change that the old-style non-static member functions with implicit instead of explicit object parameter need to have the cvref-qualified function types. Changing the type of these functions would break a lot of code, so it is too late for that.

Comment: "*instead of `void() const`*" - did you mean `void (container::*)() const` instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau No I meant the type of the function itself, although that is a bit of an abstract thing, since you can't `decltype` the function itself. I added the equivalent in terms of the pointers.

Comment: So member function types shouldn't have ever been implemented the way they are today? This whole issue arises from an oversight? That's honestly kind of disappointing, but I guess it can happen to anyone. Damn backwards-compatibility.

Comment: @NikTedig These types have been around since C++98 (although in much fewer number of combinations) and I don't think when C++98 was designed it was anticipated how templates and types would be used in these ways. The standard library didn't even have any type traits until C++11.

Comment: @NikTedig Also, non-static member functions with implicit object parameters allow for casting member function pointers inside class hierarchies, which makes sense as a OOP feature. Because the type of a pointer to a non-static member function with explicit object parameter depends on the object parameter's type as a function parameter type it can't be cast like that.

Comment: @user17732522 Interesting. Follow up question: Other than the casting thing with the member functions you talked about, can you think of any other places where it would break existing code if the type was changed? I'm probably not thinking straight, but all you would have to do is redesign some parts of the standard template library and other such libraries no? I mean how often do people actually deal with this kind of stuff in their code? Phasing out throw() probably broke way more code did it not?

Comment: @NikTedig The pointer-to-member-function types are very common. Actual references to the _function type_ derived from them are probably not common outside of library code dealing with such functions. The deprecation of `throw()` happened with C++11. I think it was easier to make breaking changes at the time, but in any case inconvenience for library implementers is probably not enough for a breaking change of that magnitude. Other breaking changes usually have better reasons, see https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.